# How to send more than one image to server

Tags: php, android, imageview, multiprocessing, bitmapfactory

My code is working for one image when I upload more then one image it show error to me .

Can anybody help me in getting out this problem?

Using below code I am able to upload single Image , but I want to upload  more then one Image so please help how can I upload Images.
Thanks

Here is my code

```
  String image_path=imageUrl1;
      GetData(myFiles);         

}


        });

}


public void GetData(String myFiles)
{

        String image_retrive_url="http://tradewale.com/open/tradedata.php?submitType=PostAd";

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PostAddActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage(" Sending...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();




    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(myFiles);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream);
    byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    String Title = title.getText().toString();
    String Description = description.getText().toString().trim();
    String PhoneNumber = phonenumber.getText().toString();
    String Email = email.getText().toString();
    String Price = price.getText().toString();


    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("photo_url", image_retrive_url));



    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() 
    {

   @Override
   public void run() {
         try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://tradewale.com/open/tradedata.php?submitType=PostAd");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                final String the_string_response = convertResponseToString(response);


            }
         catch(final Exception e)
            {
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() 
                 {

                   @Override
                   public void run() 
                   {
                       Toast.makeText(PostAddActivity.this, "ERROR " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                              
                   }
               });
                  System.out.println("Error in http connection "+e.toString());
            }  
   }
       });
   t.start();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To send more image in webservice. You have to change in `webservice` also. Add `one more` parameter in service part. so you can be able to send more than one image in one time.

and get the `base64` string of second image like `e.g. img_str2`

like :

```
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
String image_str2 = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr2);
```

and named new parameter in service like `image2`

```
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image",image_str));
 nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image2",image_str2));
```

Here `image` and `image2` is `2 diff`. parameter for images. these parameter names must also have to be `define in your service side code`.. so that service code can  save your iamges.

Comment: In this way i have created four different method

Comment: no need for four different method.. just add more parameter.

Comment: how to do that can u tell me

Comment: in webserivce code you can request more parameter for images and in your android code you have to add more parameter. see my edited answer.

Comment: String [] images=image_path.split(",");
          for (String image : images) 
         {
          
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 30, stream); 
        byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
        image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
        multipleimages=stream+",";
        
         }

Comment: this i did for multiple image can you chcek that

Comment: no you have to define diffrent parameter for diff. iamges. currently you are doing string concat that is wrong.

Comment: den how to do that we cant concat images